# Access 3d tensor by 2d index

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to access a 3d tensor matrix by 2d matrix. The return should be an 2d matrix too. And the following is what i try to achieve.

```
dim1 = 2
dim2 = 3
dim3 = 4
source = torch.FloatTensor(dim1, dim2, dim3)
source.normal_()

check = zn > 0.0
index = torch.argmax(check, dim=0)

for i in range(dim2):
    for j in range(dim3):
        ret[i, j] = source[index[i, j], i, j]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.1.0/torch.html#torch.gather), you might need to [`permute`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.1.0/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.permute) your tensor to fit the requirements of `gather.

Comment: To use gather, i need the shape of source and index is the same.